# Data not posted Correctly on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to save the form data on click of save changes button. On click of input field I wanted to save the value in some other input field but not able to do so. Can someone please help..

date get appended correctly in both the input boxes 'input field' and 'another input field' but get saved in 'input field' text box only upon save.

```
function code(){
        var p = '03/02/2022';
        $("#input_field").val(p);  // data saved on click of submit
        $("#another_input_field").val(p);  // data not saved on click of submit
} 
$(window).load(function () {
    var lat = document.getElementById('input_field');
    lat.addEventListener('click',function(){
        alert("in");
        code();
    });
});
```